# Cannot use mapbox attributes in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, attributes, mapbox

After upgrading to Mapbox SDK 5.2.0 I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\example\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
Error:error: attribute 'com.example:mapbox_styleUrl' not found.
Error:attribute 'com.example:mapbox_styleUrl' not found.
```

For some reason Gradle cannot find `mapbox_styleUrl` attribute. At first I thought that the attribute name has changed, however other attributes (for example, `mapbox_cameraZoom`) do not work either. How can I fix the error?

**build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    ...

    compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.2.0') {
        transitive=true
    }
}
```

**layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        mapbox:mapbox_styleUrl="@string/mapbox_style_url"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody has the same issue, the problem was that I included the wrong version of Mapbox SDK. It should be `com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.2.0@aar` instead of `com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.2.0` (notice `@aar` at the end).

Comment: Hey there @fdermishin , where did you update this reference ? the app build.gradle ?

Comment: @prestonsmith Yes